# AJAX Authentication Before Default AngularJS Page is Chosen

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper way of selecting the page that the user should be directed to using AngularJS with an authentication sequence?

I have looked at numerous guides but they are all very complex. Here is where I am at myself - using a controller to do AJAX post call and then on success changing the page.

What is the next step in improving my authentication technique?

Also, more specifically, how should I direct the user to the appropriate page knowing my skill level is not up to par with guides like:
https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec